# Synchronize position of items in itemscontrol

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I'm trying to create a WPF control that displays two vertical "swimlanes" (Left and Right). Both Left and Right should be databound to two separate ObservableCollection in the ViewModel. ISkill has a Name property and optionally a SynchronizedWith property that basically is a reference to another ISkill object (in the opposite collection).

The two swimlanes could be seen as ordinary vertical StackPanels but all ISkill objects that are synchronized with another ISkill object should always be aligned vertically (which means that at some places there will be empty space). ISkills that's synchronized should also have a connected line between the two different swimlanes. The attached image will probably give a better view of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image: Vertical Swimlanes]

Below is the ISkill interface.

```
public interface ISkill
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    ISkill SynchronizedWith { get; set; }
}
```

One idea I've had is to bind Left and Right to two ItemsControls and use a Grid as layout panel. But I'm not sure how the layout pass should determine which Grid.Row-index that each item in the collections should have.

All suggestions is very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: IMO it would be easier to also have a `double Level` property on the ISkill interface, which serves a vertical position (either directly or converted by a binding converter) in a Canvas used as ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl.

Comment: Both sides should be always aligned e.g. scrolled together?

Comment: I agree with Clemens. The 'level' can be calculated after applying all the constraints to the two sets. Each constraint can be a dataitem as well, and mapped to a visualization.

Comment: @Gosha Yep, both swimlanes should be synced in scrolling.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, that could be a way of doing it. But I would rather avoid adding view-specific data to the model.

Comment: Isn't that exactly why we have MVVM, with view models?

Comment: Yes, of course I could wrap the ISkill object into a VM containing a Level or Index property as well. True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is to create a dedicated view model representing an item in this view. The ObservableCollection  of those view models should be synchronized with existing collections. This approach will simplify the view design.

```
class SyncViewModel
{
    public ISkill RightItem { get;} 
    public ISkill LeftItem { get;}
    //simplifies binding 
    public bool HasLeftItem { return LeftItem!=null; }
    public bool HasRightItem { return RightItem!=null; } 
    public bool HasConnection { return HasLeftItem && HasRightItem; } 
 }
```

Comment: This is actually how I'm doing it right now and it works pretty good. So basically I have a SkillRow-class with the left and right Skill-object and the VM listens to changes in the Left and Right collections. The VM has a collection of SkillRows that aggregates the Left and Right collection and adds new SkillRows or uses existing Rows to add Skills to the Left or Right property. Maybe the solution I have is good after all...

Comment: If so, IMO you should keep the current design. The only complexity here is in synchronization and it's feels better to handle it in ViewModel.

Comment: I will mark this as accepted for now. I'm working on a different version that takes the approach that @Clemens suggest. Maybe I'll post this when it's working as intended.